# Read custom attributes from AD using graph API

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need clarification for below users graph api,

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/

We have synced our on-premise AD with Azure active directory. In my on premise AD we have the custom attribute called “RollNo”. I would like to read that " RollNo” data from above users graph api.

Is this possible to read custom attribute from AD ?

Comment: Can you see the RollNo property in your Azure AD user objects in the Azure Portal? I was under the impression that custom attributes were not supported in Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the rollno in azure AD. But I've created in On-premise AD which is synced with azure AD. Do we have any workaround to get this value?

Answer (score 0):

When configuring Azure AD Connect there is a step that allows you to specify additional attributes that you wish to be replicated to Azure AD.But the custom attributes. name would be changed.

For more detailed information, please refer to the official article: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions](http://Azure%20AD%20Connect%20sync:%20Directory%20extensions)